# Visual Studio 2013 C++ Adding Files To Project

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2013, addition, directory

Alright I'm losing my mind over this extremely simple problem.

What I have is a code directory that I want to add to my project.
Most of the files are contained in a directory and they make up a namespace. So when I want to include them in a cpp file, I type it like this:

```
 #include <directory1/source.h>
```

And I'm sure of this since it works in another project. Here is what I've done:

- So I've created an empty project.
- Copied the source files into my project source directory.
- Then went on to Visual Studio, clicked to "Show all files" button in the solution explorer.
- Right clicked the files I want to add and clicked the "include in project" button.
- Files are added to the project but it now gives me an error like this

  ```
  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'directory/source.h': No such file or directory
  ```
- I've tried to add the directories from Project Property Pages->VC++ Directories->Include Directories. It didn't work.

How can I add source files that are contained in folders in Visual Studio for C++?

EDIT: It still doesn't work. All I want to do is to add C++ files with a directory structure.

Comment: When you setup the include path settings, remember the directory that contains the *named item* is the one that must be in the path. I.e., if your path was `"c:\\myprojects\\mypath\\base\\directory\\source.h"`, your named item is `"directory\\source.h"`. It is the path to, and including, **base** that must be in the include path. Too often people add the full path to, and including, **directory** incorrectly.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is, I'm including the whole directory, source files are just inside these files. So I'm entering the path of the directory to the project but it doesn't work. I mean the whole code is inside the project source folder. Specifying #include <directory1/source.h> should be enough no?

Comment: The files you add to the project and the directories searched for include files are two completely separate things.  As @WhozCraig said, the path you use in your include directive is relative to the include paths for the project.

Comment: File inclusion in the project isn't enough. Again, if "directory" is the last thing in your addendum to your include path settings then you've gone too far. Remember you're specifying `directory` as part of your `#include` item. That item says "what" to look for, the include path says "where" to look. There is no `directory/filename.h` in the location `path/to/directory`. It would have to be called `path/to/directory/directory/filename.h` for that to work. Don't include `directory` at the end of your include path settings. just include its parent folder.

Comment: Add a reply so I can mark your answer :) just copy the thing.